# Issue saving DatePicker values to MySQL

Tags: c#, xaml

I am having trouble saving an updated value from my DatePicker object.  When I go to save it I get the following error:

"The field hex_srv_start must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '12'."

I'm kind of new to this and I haven't been able to work out, how (or where) to apply the conversion.

XAML:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Txthex_srv_start" SelectedDate="{Binding hex_srv_start}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111"/>
```

C# - here is the code I am using to save:

```
var abook = db.egw_addressbook.Local.FirstOrDefault(o => o.contact_id == 16875);
abook.org_name = mvm.org_name;
abook.hex_srv_start = mvm.hex_srv_start;
db.SaveChanges();
MessageBox.Show("Saved");
```

Update:  I needed to format the DatePicker (which is bound to a VARCHAR(12) type) within the XAML.  I was pointed to a really useful site, that shows you how this is done - best of luck.

Thanks again.

Comment: What's your db schema ? It seems like you are trying to save a Datetime into a VARCHAR(12) or something similar...

Comment: You're right - The table itself has the field as VARCHAR(12), and egw_addressbook.cs is giving me the string public string hex_srv_start { get; set; }.  So, I'm guessing I need some way of converting the DatePicker to the right format, which is "yyyy/MM/dd" - but I don't know how to do that (or indeed, if it's the way to do it).  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the DateTime into a string so your DB can save it properly.
You will probably need to change the `hex_srv_start` property of `abook`'s class to a string.

The conversion can be done by using:

```
mvm.hex_srv_start.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

If you need more help on the formatting of dates and times, this is a pretty thorough guide [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried that, but got a message in the Error List saying, "Argument 1: cannot convert from "string" to 'System.IFormatProvider' Underneath that it says,  "The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: That's because your `hex_srv_start` is already a string. Does it have a value at runtime ?

Comment: Yes it does.  If I simply change the year it fails during the save.

Comment: Then your WPF binding is probably at fault. When you change the value in the DatePicker does the value of `mvm.hex_serv_start` change also ?

Comment: It's a really basic testbed.  I created a new project, added a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model class, added the single table (and the above XAML), plus C# code to populate the database.  I'll update the question now to show this.  Thank you for all of the help.

Comment: Bun - I think I need to ask a different question.  Something along the lines of "How to convert a XAML DatePicker object into a foramtted string".  What do you think?

Comment: @AndyDB Take a look at that article, it explains everything you need to know about DateTime and WPF to complete your goal : http://bretstateham.com/binding-to-the-new-xaml-datepicker-and-timepicker-controls-to-the-same-datetime-value/. You should also try to put all your logic in the ViewModel instead of the code behind, it's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Bun, I seem to be getting few things wrong on this site.  What should I do to close this question down (without irritating everyone).  Also, I think your link is going to point me in the right direction, so is there anything I can do to award points (or something).

Comment: @AndyDB To award points you can Upvote my answer and/or accept it. You don't need to close it, leaving it inactive will do the trick !